# TwitterPopTags Scala Spark not able to access Oauth information I think

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, spark-streaming

I have been trying to preform a static pull for some information using Scala, Spark, and intellij IDEA, and I have been running into this error for quite some time. I have already added in the streaming dependency,and all the required jar files, however I keep getting this error.

I've spent some time playing around with the variables, trying to manually input my oauth information (I believe that's what's causing this error) and I've tried making a twitter4j.properties files in my spark root, project root, and even my project source file root.

```
Usage: TwitterPopularTags <consumer key> <consumer secret> <access token> <access token secret> [<filters>]
```

`Process finished with exit code 1`

That is the error I keep getting. Attached is screenshot. 
Also, once I get this working (oauth) how can I modify the information I pull from twitter and potentially store it using a local SQL database, or even a csv file?

Thanks![The error][1]

Source code for TwitterPopularTags: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/TwitterPopularTags.scala

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPSOg.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to figure this out, you can do the following to provide arguments to the array that the example provides you with, and expects your oauth information in:
do the following:

1)      Edit your configuration (click the configuration drop-down and select “edit configurations”.

2)      Under the “Configuration” tab you will see “Program arguments” field

3)      In this program arguments field, enter the four arguments as required by the code, delimited by a whitespace.